# How to implement Linq extensions in custom method?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq, c#-4.0

I have a method where I use Linq to filter it and convert it to a List, but it is turned into a list to early for requested calls. See the custom method example here:

```
public IEnumerable<ItemModel> GetAll()
{
    var output = new List<ItemModel>();

    this.DataLayer.GetItems() //returns IQueryable<SomeWeirdItemModel>
        .Where(i => i.IsActive == true) 
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(i => output.Add(new ItemModel(i)));

    return output;
}
```

The problem is when I do `this.GetAll().Where(i => i.StartDate >= DateTime.Now)`, my custom method is turning it into a List which retrieves EVERYTHING from the database, then my request filters by date. How do I get the called Linq and implement it into my custom method?

Something like this?
`this.DataLayer.GetNewsItems().Where(i => i.IsActive == true && (REQUESTED FILTER HERE?))`

Comment: By not calling `ToList()`.  The ToList call is what's causing the DataLayer query to execute.  You can add additional filtering as needed, and the Linq statement will only execute (including your filters) when you call for output.

Comment: Perhaps if you included your code for `GetNewsItems()` it might help.  Also, if yo uwere to include the database technology you're using it would help as well.

Comment: @Robert, then I can't use ForEach to do the conversion. Also I still won't know what the requested filter was.

Comment: It's a 3rd party framework that I am wrapping, so it's embedded in a DLL that I have no control over.

Comment: Well, what does `GetNewsItems()` return?  That must be documented.

Comment: There's a `ForEach<T>` extension method that I could dig up that will work on an `IQueryable`, but there's probably better ways to do this, like a `select` clause in your linq.   Are these user-selectable filters?  If so, you may need [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) or [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

Comment: @Mystere Man, I updated the code, it returns a totally different model that I need to convert to another list of simplified models.

Comment: It returns `IQueryable<SomeWeirdItemModel>`

Comment: How are you obtaining the filter?  What does the filter look like?

Comment: Do you have control over the definition of ItemModel?  If so, changing it to use property initializers instead of a constructor argument would help a great deal.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, and add a bit of guessing: you want to go from `IQueryable<SomeWeirdItemModel>` to `IQueryable<ItemModel>`, without actually executing a query? I.e.: you want this type conversion to be done in the database? This just isn't possible, the DB can't call arbitrary C# code, much less filter further based on its results. If you don't need this to be done in the DB, then the data will first have to be loaded anyway, and you don't need to bother getting rid of that step.

Comment: Although `ToList().ForEach(...)` is still silly here, replacing it with `AsEnumerable().Select(...)` and returning an `IEnumerable<ItemModel>` should work. (In fact, `.ForEach()` is silly everywhere.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems here.

The first is that ToList() will return all the items that match the Where clause from your database.  You cannot do a ToList() and have the query NOT be executed immediately.

Second, you're returning `IEnumerable<ItemModel>`.  IEnumerables also immediately execute the query.  You have to return an `IQueryable<ItemModel>` if you want to add additional parameters to the returned type.

Third, it may be difficult to make this work with a Constructor argument, since this requires processing in code, rather than in the database.  <s>@dasblinkenlight's solution may work, although I can't test it.  I'd assume he knows what he's talking about.</s>

You need to change his code to this:

```
public IQueryable<ItemModel> GetAll()
{
    return this.DataLayer.GetNewsItems()
       .Where(i => i.IsActive) 
       .Select((v,i) => new ItemModel(i));
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you insist on using a constructor argument for your projected type, then you will have to compromise somewhere, such as passing the filter to your method.

Something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ItemModel> GetItemsByDate(DateTime date)
{
    return this.DataLayer.GetNewsItems()
       .Where(i => i.IsActive && i.Date == date)
       .AsEnumerable()
       .Select(x => new ItemModel(x));
}
```

This will still execute the query when you call the method (you can't apply any more filters to the output and have it execute in the database), but it will only return the objects that match the IsActive and Date filters.

You could also apply an arbitrary expression like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ItemModel> GetItemsByDate(Expression<Func<SomeWeirdItemModel,bool>> filter)
{
    return this.DataLayer.GetNewsItems()
       .Where(i => i.IsActive && filter)
       .AsEnumerable()
       .Select(x => new ItemModel(x));
}
```

Then you can simply do this:

```
var items = DataLayer.GetAll(x => x.Date == date);
var others = DataLayer.GetAll(x => x.Date == date && x.Title.Length > 5 && x.Test = "X");
// etc..
```

Unfortunately, you will have to expose SomeWeirdModel in the parameter, because the expression has to filter on it, otherwise you would have to do a lot of work to try and translate the filter.

Comment: `i` isn't an index in the OP's context; it's just a lambda variable.  I'm assuming that the OP's constructor already performs the data conversion.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Do you have a suggestion for materializing the projection with a constructor argument without converting to L2O?

Comment: It would be custom code in the constructor, but really all he needs is a `select` projection.  I don't think that's what his problem is.  If you read the question carefully, he wants the Linq statement to stop giving him the entire data set, and the only way to do that is to improve the filtering before the `ToList` call, or remove the ToList altogether and add filtering downstream.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - My point is that the constructor argument tends to not work in an Entity query, because it can't be converted to SQL.  If the class requires a constructor argument, I don't see any way to make that work.

Comment: I don't see anything in the OP about EF.  It might be, but I think you're just assuming it is.  The OP is saying it's a custom DLL that returns an `IQueryable<SomeClass>`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, there's mention of `IQueryable`. Inconclusive, but not an unreasonable assumption.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I'm making an assumption that it's EF, since he did not bother to answer my question about the database technology used.  He's saying it's a database and an IQueryable, so regardless there is likely some kind of sql translation.

Comment: Regardless, if it's an `IQueryable` it ought to be lazy.  That's the whole point of it being `IQueryable`.  If it's really prematurely firing because EF is not understanding his date filter, well, then it really sucks to be EF.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Yes, because he wants to apply further filters to the returned query, and have those filters all execute in the database lazily, but he's wrapping another model and projecting it into another for some unknown reason.  He's using the ForEach because he needs to materialize the objects with constructor arguments.

Comment: `select (x => new ItemModel { prop1 = x.someProperty, ..etc })`   ...But yes, I understand what you are saying.  I still think his problem is that the date filter isn't working properly before he gets to the `ToList()` call, but he hasn't clarified that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - One would assume because he's using a constructor argument, he's not using any public properties with setters.  Why else use the constructor argument?

Comment: `select (x => new ItemModel(x))`.  I just don't see any problem there.  He doesn't need the ToList, and if he's filtering *after* the ToList, it's too late.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - the date filter is intended to be applied to the returned `IQueryable` object, not within his `GetAll()` method.  he wants to do `GetAll().Where(x => x.Date == date)`..  That's why it requires the IQueryable to be returned from the method.

Comment: Thx for all the input. The model constructor is doing the conversion by just mapping the properties (this.Title = param.Title in the constructor). This is because the original model from the framework is bloated and not even serializable. This is to get clean web services implemented. It's supposed to be an elegant hack instead of rewritting the framework source code.

Comment: @TruMan1: Well, now that you're back, maybe you can clarify for us how the date filter works?  Since you never put it in your original code, but you imply that it is there somehow.  What does that look like?

Comment: The date filter was an example in the second paragraph of how the custom method will be used by devs. So here are some other examples:
this.GetAll().Where(i => i.StartDate >= DateTime.Now);
this.GetAll().Where(i => i.Title.Length >= 5);
this.GetAll().Where(i => i.Test != "X");